# Laravel app:abort(404) not showing 404 page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, http-status-code-404

I have a route of /path/{id}, and I want my controller to detect when the id is invalid and product a 404 error page. I tried using `App::abort(404);`, but this doesn't produce a 404 error - just a generic exception. How do I make it generate a 404 page?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Response::make or Response::view functions to generate a specific page. You can pass the error code as an argument to that. Like this:

```
Response::make("Page not found", 404);
```

Or to use a specific view, use:

```
return Response::view('404', array(), 404);
```

To display the view app/views/404.php with the http response code 404. Remember to replace the slashes with dots for the view name, so if your file is at app/views/errors/404.php, you will need to use the view name 'errors.404' for laravel to find it.

More information here: http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.Facades.Response.html